# ngx-translate: Translate string in Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, ngx-translate

I can get the value if it's a static test, but whenever I'm trying to get the translated value (using `ngx-translate`), it's empty.

```
<div id="header-title">
    <h1>{{ 'MENU_TITLE' | translate | uppercase }}</h1>
</div>
```

**This works** and returns `Test`

```
<div id="header-title">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

**spec.ts**

```
it('should translate a string using the key value', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
    const title = fixture.nativeElement;
    console.log(title.querySelector('#header-title h1').innerHTML);
});
```

**Importing translate module**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                        deps: [HttpClient]
                    }
                }),
                HttpClientModule
            ],
            declarations: [NavComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        injector = getTestBed();
        translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
    }));
```

**-----FIXED-----** but not sure if this is the right way to do

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavComponent>;

it('should translate a string using the key value', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges() // fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
    const title = fixture.nativeElement;
    console.log(title.querySelector('#header-title h1').innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Add full example!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution to translate a key in `Unit Testing`

First you check if your `textContent` equals the translate key. Then you set a translation for that key and check again if it translated:

```
it('should translate a string using the key value', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('#header-title h1').textContent).toEqual('MENU_TITLE');
    translate.setTranslation('en', { MENU_TITLE: 'reporting' });
    translate.use('en');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(compiled.querySelector('#header-title h1').textContent).toEqual('REPORTING');
}));
```

Comment: What will be the import for `translate.setTranslation` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to test this for a unit test.

The reason it doesn't work is that the translate pipe is async with the log happening while it is still retrieving the value.

I am going to assume you are already providing the TranslateModule in the TestBed.

Now, I am not sure if this will 100% work, so maybe you can give it a go. However, in theory, you can try using async and whenStable():

```
  it(
    'should translate a string using the key value',
    async(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
      const title = fixture.nativeElement;

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(title.querySelector('#header-title h1').innerHTML);
      });
    })
  );
```

Good luck :)!

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work. However when I remove in `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);` in my code and replace it with `fixture.detectChanges();`.. This returns 'MENU_TITLE' still not what I want because I need the translation, but at least it's not empty anymore. Not sure if my workaround is the good way though

Comment: Can I please see how you are providing the translate module? You must provide the loader so it knows where to get the translations (the same way you provide it in the app.module.ts. For more information: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636

Comment: Added in the question